# Tweak load balancer for docker swarm mode

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm, haproxy, docker-swarm-mode

I want a lead to the below problem.

**My understanding:**

Docker swarm incorporates an ingress and a DNS server that identifies services with their names. It also incorporates inbuilt robust load balancers on every node in the cluster.
We can hit any service running on different nodes which are participating in docker swarm mode using any machine's IP address. If a machine does not host service, the load balancer will route the request to a different machine that hosts that service.
For best practice, we can choose a load balancer container(NGINX/HAProxy) as a reverse proxy to route the requests on the basis of some predefined algorithms(round-robin/Hash/IP Hash/Least Connection/Least bandwidth, etc.).

**Problem statement:**

I want to make a cluster of two/three different machines where I will be deploying all the technical services which are required. A mini QA environment.

As a service is identified by its name, I can not create another service with the same name. Being a developer, I want to have a service up and running on my localHost which is also part of the docker swarm cluster. Obviously, I can not name it the same. So, let's say I name it as myIP_serviceName. Now the DNS entry which docker swarm has will be based on this name.

I want a mechanism where if I make a call for any service using my IP address as host, the load balancer will look for any service which is registered in DNS as myIP_serviceName, if it finds any service with such a name call should be routed to this service, if it doesn't, the call should follow the regular path. This should hold true for every consecutive request which is part of a round trip journey.

I have not explored Kubernetes yet, Please suggest if Kubernetes can be used here to achieve this goal more elegantly.

Please correct my understanding if I am wrong and **do provide valuable suggestions**.

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy have written about [HAProxy on Docker Swarm: Load Balancing and DNS Service Discovery](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-on-docker-swarm-load-balancing-and-dns-service-discovery/) maybe this will point you in the right direction.